# Create 4 image button at the 4 corners of the layout

Tags: android-layout

I have created a layout with 4 Imagebuttons at 4 corners. i have to put my own imagebutton. say the imagebutton width is 80 dp, instead i have to put my own imagebutton independent of the width and height

Comment: So what exactly is ur issue?

Comment: IS it possible to define custom image in the place of image button...? That Image should act as an ImageButton .